# How to find mean of remaining months in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Could you help me this Matlab codes?
I want to get average of the remaining months for example,

Let assume that my year-based is start from June to May (not Jan-Dec).

When t= Jun, then my expected value will be mean of the next month (July) to the end of 12 months cycle (May) of next year .
This process should repeat again such as, 
if t = Apr then expected value is only May. But when t = May then my expected value will repeat again as mean from June to May.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify what is "mean of months", with an example of how you calculate mean of several months?

Comment: Dear friend. For example, I have a data : Jan = 1; Feb =4; Mar = 6; Apr = 9; ... Dec = 3.  If (t) = 1 (Jan) then my expected value (X) will be next month to end of year = average(4+6+8...+3). this cycle will repeat again. I hope my writing makes sense to you.

Comment: How is the data stored? An what is its size?

Comment: Let's say that, i have monthly flow data from 2000 - 2010. I also have an additional 1 year rainfall data in 2012. I want to multiply rainfall with 10 year flow data month by month. Eg. Jan 2000 of flow x average rainfall (Feb 2012, Mar 2012 ...Dec 2012).  Jan 2001 of flow x average rainfall (Feb 2012, Mar 2012 ...Dec 2012), etc.

Comment: If you look at the picture i attached you will get easy what i want your helps.

Comment: From image is an example, you can define wherever Jan - Dec or June -May that is not the problem. The problem is how to get an average data for the next month to end of year when calculate for the present month. Ex. The code is look alike :  For t = 1 : 12;   A(t) = mean(t+1,12);   If t==12 then t=1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you, you can store the data of the year of which you average as an array, say named x, of size 12.
Then, given a scalar t between 1 to 12,, you can calculate the "remaining average" y by:

```
y = (t<12)*mean(x(t+1:end)) + (t==12)*mean(x);
```

Or more compactly:

```
y = mean( x(1+mod(t, 12) : end) ) ;
```

Note that if you have many such calculations, you might preallocate an array of the above y and then use y(t) rather than calculate it again.

Comment: Thank you, but the code is still not worked for me. it shown that "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals "

Comment: Also the first line? I assumed t is indeed integer between 1:12.

Comment: Corrected the 2nd option

Comment: Yes, the first line also, i added t = 1:12 and given (x) is input data. The calculation mean value for y(t) seems in-correct.

Comment: Can you try with scalar t?

Comment: Please check with a single value of t, say t=12

Comment: Dear Matanj. Your second line is correct now. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help!